# Filter Navigation Property Entity Framework, returns NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to use a navigation property but when I use it I'm getting an error

> Value cannot be null.

Which is understandable since the People collection is NULL, but why is it NULL?

What I'm really trying to do is select the name of the Requestor by RequestorPersonID(last line of the last code snippet)

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]     
    public int PersonID { get; set; }         
    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
} 
public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
public class FrDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int FrID { get; set; }      
    public int RequestorPersonID { get; set; }
    virtual public IList<Person> People { get; set; }
}
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{      
       public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
       public DbSet<FrDetail> FrDetails { get; set; }    
} 

public ViewResult List()
{
    EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    IQueryable<FrDetail> frDetails = context.FrDetails.Include(x => x.People);
    return View(frDetails);
}

//The view

@model IQueryable<FrDetail>   
@foreach (var p in Model)
    Html.RenderPartial("FunctionRequestSummary", p);
}

//Partial View FunctionRequestSummary

@model FrDetail
@Model.People.Count()//IT'S ALWAYS ZERO
//@Model.People//NULL
@Model.People.Where(x=>x.PersonID==Model.RequestorPersonID).FirstOrDefault().FirstName
```

The problem comes in the last line where the count is always 0. I'v tried switching

> ProxyCreationEnabled = false; and LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

This didn't help either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're going for?

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]     
    public int PersonID { get; set; }         
    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
} 
public class Employee : Person
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
public class FrDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int FrID { get; set; }      
    public virtual Person RequestorPerson { get; set; }
}
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{      
       public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
       public DbSet<FrDetail> FrDetails { get; set; }    
} 

public ViewResult List()
{
    EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    IQueryable<FrDetail> frDetails = context.FrDetails;
    return View(frDetails);
}

//The view

@model IQueryable<FrDetail>   
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("FunctionRequestSummary", p);
}

//Partial View FunctionRequestSummary

@model FrDetail
@Model.RequestorPerson.FirstName
```

Comment: I've tried ICollection and IList with no success. Model.People is still NULL

Comment: Have you used ICollection with proxy creation and lazy loading enabled?

Comment: Well now that I look at your code a bit closer, it makes sense that you're not getting anything in your Person collection--your Person class doesn't have a property that refers to an FrDetail record.